# What is the story behind ${#} in bash

Tags: string, bash, string-length

I came across string length manipulation in bash 4.1.2 for two strings

First:  `1000000000000000000`

```
developer@kernel ~> echo ${#1000000000000000000}
0
developer@kernel ~> s1=1000000000000000000
developer@kernel ~> echo ${#s1}
19
```

Second: `10000000000000000000`

```
developer@kernel ~> echo ${#10000000000000000000}
19
developer@kernel ~> s2=10000000000000000000
developer@kernel ~> echo ${#s2}
20
```

How to explain the strange those behaviors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`${#var}` is normally the length in characters of `${var}`. So `${#1000000000000000000}` is the length of the 1000000000000000000th argument to the script. Since your script wasn't called with that many arguments, this is zero.

Apparently there's a limit on the number of positional parameters, and when you try to refer to a parameter beyond that, the results are unpredictable, and varies from system to system.  The dividing line appears to be `${#9223372036854775808}`, which is 2<sup>64</sup>.

Comment: but the length of 10000000000000000000 is 20, why ${#10000000000000000000} goes to 19?

Comment: @hylepo I get 20 for `echo ${#10000000000000000000}`.

Comment: @BallPython What does `echo ${0}` return? How long is it?

Comment: @Barmar, have you noticed what is the version number of your bash?

Comment: I tried this on OS X running bash 3.2.48. I'll try it now on Linux running 4.1.5 and see what I get

Comment: Weird, it returns 25.

Comment: I think this answer already hits the point of the question. It make no much sense to argument about why ${#xxxxxxxxxxxxx} returns what value, since no one wants to access that positional parameter, and it's beyond the limit anyway.

Only the maintainer/developer of bash should be worried about it for security reason.

Comment: @Barmar, $0 is "-bash" if you are in bash prompt, which has the length of 5.

Comment: `${#9223372036854775807}` is 0. `${#9223372036854775808}` is 18. The upper bound is 2**63-1 (at least on my system).

Comment: @KeithThompson The length of the string format of 9223372036854775808 is 19, so why ${#9223372036854775808} shows 18?

Comment: I think we've already established that this behavior is unpredictable. On my Linux system it shows 25.

Comment: @Barmar so would you like to improve your answer and then we can close the discussion, since "it just returns the length of the name" is not exactly